# jQuery mobile controlgroup horizontal layout issue

Tags: jquery, browser, mobile, jquery-mobile

jQuery mobile 1.0 seems to have a layout problem with **controlgroup** of type **horizontal**. Any help is appreciated.

UI Code:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
<legend>Date of Birth</legend>

<select name="SelDateOfBirthMonth" id="SelDateOfBirthMonth">
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <option value="jan">January</option>
    <option value="feb">February</option>
    <option value="mar">March</option>
</select>

<select name="SelDateOfBirthDay" id="SelDateOfBirthDay">
    <option value="">Day</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select name="SelDateOfBirhtYear" id="SelDateOfBirhtYear">
    <option value="">Year</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2019">2009</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
```

[jQuery Mobile Layou http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/470/jqmobilecontrol.jpg](http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/470/jqmobilecontrol.jpg)

Comment: if either answer helped you please accept one or the other. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having this problem when the controls are definitely narrow enough to fit. only seems to happen on chrome browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to jQuery Mobile docs (emphasis mine):

> By adding the data-type="horizontal" attribute to the controlgroup
>   container, you can swap to a horizontal-style group that floats the
>   buttons side-by-side and sets the width to only be large enough to fit
>   the content. **(Be aware that these will wrap to multiple lines if the
>   number of buttons or the overall text length is too wide for the
>   screen.)**

Here's the [link to the doc](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/buttons/buttons-grouped.html)

Comment: +! as I think this is the cause

Comment: but this is causing my buttons to wrap, even though they are well under the size needed (only in chrome browser, too)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing, but was able to solve it without using special CSS by adding `data-mini="true"` to my select tags.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're following the example code here:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/selects/

And it looks fine when I reproduce it here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jmHTc/1/

Is it nested in any other tags that might be padding it and causing it to display like this?

Could you truncate the names like this?

- http://jsfiddle.net/jmHTc/3/

as Brian pointed out there is also the chance of it just being to large to fit the screen

Answer (score 0):

You need to override both the portrait and landscape classes in this instance. jQM is trying to be intelligent, but it's calculations did not work well for me. Just use firebug with your browser skinny vs. wide to see how jQM is applying the classes as the width changes. It will add and remove the .ui-field-contain class when you switch to portrait or your display port goes skinny in your browser.

You are looking to override the width and display (inline-block) of these if you set them all identical, you will see what I mean:

.ui-field-contain .ui-controlgroup-controls{}

.ui-controlgroup-controls{}

.ui-field-contain .ui-controlgroup-label{}

.ui-controlgroup-label{}

Answer (score 0):

I added **display: inline-flex;** ... don't ask me why though cuz I don't know.

```
<span id        = "blah"
      data-role = "controlgroup" 
      data-type = "horizontal"  
      style     = "display: inline-flex;"
    >
  <a ...>
  <a ...>
</span>
```

Comment: inline-flex is part of the flexible box model, which does not have great overall support yet (there have been several implementations so far with different property names, and they all behave differently). Suggestion is to not use flexible box model until the specification is a hammered out and implemented consistently.

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome inspector, it looks like the width is being set to 78% for .ui-field-contain and .ui-controlgroup-controls. Removing this width does set the buttons so that they all show up on one line.

I was able to work around the issue by adding the following rule in my own .css file:

```
.ui-field-contain .ui-controlgroup-controls {
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is correct, it does not solve the problem.

I'll suggest one troubleshooting check, and two workarounds.

1. Make sure that any containers are not limiting the space that is available to the controlgroup div.
2. Try using the `ui-mini` class in the control group div.  This will make your buttons smaller.
3. Give a negative margin to the control group.  Some people will call this a hack, but it works and is valid.  Check out [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/) for more info.

2 and 3:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-mini" style="margin-right: -10px;">
    <!-- buttons and whatnot... -->
</div>
```